# How to organize communinaction between 3 list view adapters

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have 3 list views and 3 adapters correspondingly. Then class Menu, that contains ArrayList of Products, where Product is also a class.

1st adapter contains ArrayList and display all menus in ListView1.

2nd must contain and display all Products from Menu, selected in 1st adapter.

3rd must contain all available products, that are not in 2nd ListView.

The question is, how organize architecture in such way, that selecting one item from first ListView affect 2nd and 3rd Adapters. I mean do I need to create a new class, that will hold all changes, or it is better to make ArrayLists static and call their updates from OnClickListeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that the 2nd and 3rd views wouldn't even be displayed until a selection was made on 1st view, no?

Regardless, if 2 and 3 are exclusionary drawing from the same list of products, it sounds like you should be able to build them using the same underlying data source. How are you populating these adapters? A content provider sounds like it would suite this well if you have a large enough product list.

In terms of behaviour, when a selection is made on the 1st view, that should cause a refresh of your 2nd and 3rd views on the newly changed parameters. So if in the 1st view the user has selected a number of menus which contain products, the 2nd view should do a query of some kind using the selected menus as a key for which products to then display. The 3rd view would just be what's left over, or use the selected menu as sort of a reserve key, i.e. only get products not in said menus, which would be a minor change to the query.